# Перенос сайта с denwer на хостинг

Tags: denwer, hosting, php

Всем привет! Явно же все заливали свой сайт на хостинг с денвера?

Я сколько не заливаю с денвера на хост - результат совсем другой. В денвере показывает все идеально, а как только залить на хост... Кодировка меняется вся. Куча ошибок и т.д.
Кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией и как с ней боролся.
Готов выслушать любые предложения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явно конфигурация Денвера и Хостинга не совпадает.

Проверьте конфигурацию, не используйте не поддерживаемых хостингом утилит (проверьте `phpinfo`). При чтении с базы, также проверяйте кодировку.

Comment: Хороший совет. Надеюсь с администраторами можно договориться чтобы что-нибудь поменять.

Comment: Наверное лучше использовать VPS?

Comment: Если не можете разобраться с обычным хостингом, VPS не лучше :).

Answer (score 1):

Сформулируйте проблему четче. Что именно не так работает?
Кодировка всего сайта? тогда в .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf8
```

С базы данных приходит в другой кодировке? тогда в место подключения к БД пишем

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Кодировочку на свою сменить не забудьте.
Проверьте, при переносе базы могла побиться кодировка, используйте утилиты типа  SXD

Опишите подробно что именно не работает и мы дадим вам ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. С кодировкой разобрался. Но есть еще одна проблема: Использую coigniter для разработки. В нем есть функция защиты от csrf, то есть защита от межсайтовых запросов. На лок сервере Denwer все работало, если указать в конфигурафии адрес сайт, то все функции отправки данных работают - POST. Перенес сайт на хостинг, изменил в конфиге адрес сайта - защита перестала работать, хотя все правильно. Кто работал с code-igniter? За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один из важных моментов: меняйте адрес локального хоста(то бишь http://localhost/) на ссылку вашего сайта(http://site/). Делаете экспорт своей базы данных, открываете блокнотом и меняете пути опцией "Заменить". 
Для коддинга также советую использовать альтернативу блокнота Notepad++. На панели есть пункт "Кодировка". Выбираете **Utf-8 (Без BOM)** и сохраняете. Проблем после этих процедур как правило станет меньше.

Comment: Если сохраняется с BOM, то должна показываться ошибка типа 'Warning: Cannot add header information - headers already sent by...'

Answer (score 0):

Еще задать режим показа ошибок `error_reporting` и `display_errors`